# Does this shell script docker container idiom have a name?

Tags: shell, docker

Here's a trick I've been using to get a script to execute itself inside a `docker` container:

```
#!/bin/sh

export THIS="$(readlink -f "$0")"
if [ "--raw" = "${1:-}" ]; then
    echo "inside: $(uname -a)"
else
    echo "outside: $(uname -a)"
    docker container run \
           --env THIS \
           --interactive \
           --mount type=bind,source="${THIS}",target="${THIS}",readonly \
           --rm \
           alpine sh -c "${THIS} --raw"
fi
```

Does this idiom have a name? The best I've been able to come up with is "self-dockerizing shell script"

Comment: That's very clever and interesting, but I think you have to be careful with this.  The great thing about docker is that it includes the entire runtime userspace - not just the shell itself, but the system utilities it relies on to do all but the simplest, built-in operations.  Here you have to assume that the `alpine` container has everything that `$THIS` expects to execute.  Of course, if you can be sure of that, it's not an issue.

Comment: Not related to what you asked. I think it is missing an `exit` at the end of the `else` block to avoid running the script on the host too.

Comment: @DanFarrell, you're completely correct; i.e., most of the debugging I do on scripts like this is chasing dependencies inside the container.

Comment: @Robert, the depicted script seems to behave in the desired fashion on my docker host. Is it not working for you?

Comment: I don't think you need an `exit` in the script because the shell will automatically exit when the last command completes, right?  IF it was written `if not in dcker; then run docker; fi; run command ` then I'd agree with you.

Comment: Why not package `$THIS` into an image using a Dockerfile?  I agree with @DanFarrell that this is a little too clever; this is not a normal "idiom" I've seen anywhere else.

Comment: @DavidMaze, excellent question. I prefer a script like this over a Dockerfile when the container has to work with state information that is either unknown at image build time and/or changes faster than your typical docker image. One example is a CI pipeline that must build every commit to a given source repository using an image maintained by a third party.

Comment: @rubicks I didn't try the script. When visually following the execution, it's evident that whatever comes after `fi` is executed twice. Once inside container and once on the host.

Comment: @Robert: There is no code after `fi`.  All the code in the example is in the `if` body, which works fine.  Your concern assumes that there is a body of the script after the `fi` but that's not true of the example and may not be true of the real code either.